# SharePoint web application not accessible outside the server machine

Tags: web-application, access-denied, page-not-found

I created a new SharePoint web application at port 100. I created a default site collection. When I try to access it from the server machine it opens just fine. When I try to access it from a different machine I get page not found error. Both machines belong to the same network and the same domain. What do I need to set up (in IIS, I guess) to make it work?

Please note that I do have another web application set up at port 80 which opens just fine from both machines.

Comment: Did you check the firewalls (on both machines?)

Comment: ^What he said. Yeah, I'd stick to using port numbers above 1023 for additional web applications. Ports below that are well-known ports, and are often in use. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers

Comment: @Dribbel Thank you, the firewall was the cause of the problem. Much appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should open up port 100 on the firewall by using Windows Firewall with Advanced Security.

Inbound Rules > Port > Protocol:TCP, Specific Port: 100 > Allow the connection > Apply to all zones > Enter a rule name > Finish.